# Need SQL to merge to data points into one effective dated table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-range

I have the inbound data coming in the file as below. It has `EmployeeID`, `ManagerStartDate`, `ManagerID`, `JobStartDate`, `JobID` columns. This file *always* contains the latest row.

Here are the sample rows:

```
EmployeeID,ManagerStartDate,ManagerID,JobStartDate,JobID
1001,11/1/2020,M1001,10/1/2020,J01
1002,08/1/2020,M1001,11/13/2020,J02
1003,null,null,9/1/2020,J01
```

I would need to read this data every day and store the result into a effective dated table which has columns as `EmployeeID`, `ManagerID`, `JobID`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`.

My expected output:

```
EmployeeID | ManagerID | JobID | StartDate  | EndDate
-----------+-----------+-------+------------+------------
1001       | null      | J01   | 10/01/2020 | 10/31/2020
1001       | M1001     | J01   | 11/01/2020 | 12/31/9998
1002       | M1001     | null  | 08/01/2020 | 11/12/2020
1002       | M1001     | J02   | 11/13/2020 | 12/31/9998
1003       | null      | J01   | 09/01/2020 | 12/31/9998
```

When any changes happened to the `ManagerID` and `JobID` in the next day's file, which reflects the latest data, I need to compare against the data present in the table and make the udpates as necessary.

I tried with different sets of SQL but I am stuck and I am not able to narrow down all the different scenarios. Could someone help me with guiding the solution to get the expected output?

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to start with a list of employee/date combinations and then bring in the most recent manager and job using `apply`:

```
with ed as (
      select employeeid, managerstartdate as startdate
      from t
      union. -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select employeeid, jobstartdate as startdate
      from t
     )
select ed.*, m.managerid, j.jobid,
       dateadd(day, -1,
               lead(startdate, 1, '9999-01-01') over (partition by employeeid order by startdate)
              ) as enddate
from ed outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.managerid
      from t t2
      where t2.employeeid = ed.employeeid and
            t2.managerstartdate <= ed.startdate
      order by t2.managerstartdate desc
     ) m outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.jobid
      from t t2
      where t2.employeeid = ed.employeeid and
            t2.jobstartdate <= ed.startdate
      order by t2.jobstartdate desc
     ) j;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, how do we get the desired EndDates?

Comment: @Naveen . . . You can use `lead()`.

Comment: Excellent, this clearly shows my limited knowledge in SQL and you are really good at it.
I have a follow up on how to keep this table maintained with next day's data. Here is an example, for Employee 1001 it has changed to as below in the next day's file.

EmployeeID,ManagerStartDate,ManagerID,JobStartDate,JobID

1001,12/1/2020,M1002,10/1/2020,J01

How do the same SQL would update the existing record to maintain the Manager values as it is M1001 till 11/30/2020 and from start date of 12/1/2020 the manager as M1002 where as no changes to the JobID.